# Derivation of bounds of convergence of infinite tower

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinity

If you want to solve for  $$\large{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^.}}}}=2}$$ With an infinite tower of $x$ 
 You say that there is a copy on top and say $x^2$=2 and then solve to get $x$=${\pm}{\sqrt{2}}$ . 
 but if you solve for : (using same technique )$$\large{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^.}}}}=4}$$ 
 you again get $x$=${\pm}{\sqrt{2}}$ ( this can of course can not be true ) 
 And so  there is a theorem that states 
  If :**$$\large{e^{-e} {\le}x{\le}} e^{1/e}$$** and **$$\large{{1/e}{\le}y{\le} e}$$** for $x$ being the value that is infinitely exponentiated  and y being a value that it converges to. 
 then
 the infinite tower will  converge to y  
 
 Since for the four case y>e it does not converge to 4 .And since the two case satisfies the inequalities it converges to 2  
 Q: I want to know how to rigorously derive these bounds

Comment: I think this has been asked here already, I guess soon someone will post a link to a duplicate.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence/890911#890911

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of tetration sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence)

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis what about bounds for y?

Comment: @MarkS. what about bounds for y?

Comment: Minimum is verified at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2706270/26369), but I couldn't quickly find a post verifying the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The OP says: *this of course can not be true*.
But that's only for the power tower as such.
What seems to have been considered instead, however, is the *inverse function* of the tower:
$$
y = x^{x^{.^{.^{.^.}}}} = x^y \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x = y^{1/y}
$$
Scaling in $y$-direction is three times scaling in $x$-direction in the picture below, for good reasons.

[image]

While the power tower itself is not defined outside the interval $e^{-e} \le x \le e^{1/e}$, the inverse function, when considered apart from
the former, is defined, not only for $\,1/e \le y \le e\,$ but for a much larger domain, namely $\,0 \le y \lt \infty\,$.
Details of function behaviour are described a great deal in the following MSE posting and its references:

- [Why does ${x}^{x^{x^{x^{\,.^{\,.^{\,.}}}}}}$ bifurcate below $\sim0.065$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045353/why-does-xxxx-bifurcate-below-sim0-065)

It's easy to prove that $\,\lim_{y\to\infty} y^{1/y} = 1\,$. This means that $\,x = y^{1/y}\,$ has *twofold* solutions $\,y_{1,2}\,$ for $\,1 \lt x \lt e^{1/e}\,$,
one $\,1 \lt y_1 \lt e\,$ and the other $\,e \lt y_2\,$, wich is anyway clear from the picture. Indeed the OP's solutions are among these: $\,1 \lt 2\lt e \lt 4\,$.

---

**Numerically.** Solutions of $\,y^{1/y}=x\,$ have been calculated by the (Delphi Pascal) program below.
Values of $\,x\,$ are taken from a sample array, giving accompanying $\,y_{1,2}\,$ values with
[Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).
Initial $\,y_{1,2}\,$ are taken from previous steps, starting with the two known values from the question.

```
program edit;

function Newton(y12,x : double) : double;
const
  eps : double = 1.e-9;
var
  y : double;
begin
  y := y12;
  while abs(exp(ln(y)/y)-x) > eps do
    y := y - (exp(ln(y)/y)-x) * sqr(y)/(exp(ln(y)/y)*(1-ln(y)));
  Newton := y;
end;

procedure test;
const
  x : array[0..8] of double =
 (1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.05, 1.02, 1.01, 1.001, 1.0001);
var
  y1,y2 : double;
  k : integer; 
begin
  y1 := 2; y2 := 4;
  for k := 0 to 8 do
  begin
    y1 := Newton(y1,x[k]);
    y2 := Newton(y2,x[k]);
    Writeln(x[k],' ==> (',y1,',',y2,')');
  end;
end;

begin
  test;
end.
```

**Output:**

```
 1.40000000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.88666330624630E+0000, 4.41029279309327E+0000)
 1.30000000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.47098895928257E+0000, 7.85706535100170E+0000)
 1.20000000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.25773454121357E+0000, 1.47674583809828E+0001)
 1.10000000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.11178201104165E+0000, 3.82287327653121E+0001)
 1.05000000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.05270345488064E+0000, 9.28715283791938E+0001)
 1.02000000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.02041238660200E+0000, 2.85536314597273E+0002)
 1.01000000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.01010152374054E+0000, 6.51100334614211E+0002)
 1.00100000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.00100100150234E+0000, 9.12312634995737E+0003)
 1.00010000000000E+0000 ==> ( 1.00010001000084E+0000, 1.16676997475209E+0005)
```

It is seen that the $\,y_1\,$ values near $\,y=1\,$ are close to $\,x\,$. Which should not be surprising,
because $1^{1/1}=1$ and $\,\left. dx/dy\right|_{y=1}=1\,$. But I have no decent estimate for the "far away" solutions $\,y_2\,$.

Comment: By substituting $u=1/y$ the function $x=y^{1/y}$ is mapped onto $x=u^{-u}$. Which has a value $1$ for $u\to 0$ and a derivative $dx/du(u\to 0)\to\infty$.
The latter is a measure for the _error_ in the outcomes for $u\to 0\;$ i.e. $y\to\infty$.
This makes me think that _there does not exist_ any decent approximation for the "far away" $y_2$ values.